# Registering fonts in itext 2.1.7

Tags: fonts, itext

I have converted html tp pdf using iText 2.1.7 and I need to register a font that supports Arabic data. How can this be achieved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `FontFactory.register()` as follows:

```
FontFactory.register("c:/windows/fonts/whatever_font.ttf", "arabic");
```

And then subsequently use the registered font. For example:

```
Font arabicFont = FontFactory.getFont("arabic");
Paragraph p = new Paragraph("Your text", arabicFont));
```

An [example](http://itextpdf.com/examples/iia.php?id=212) can be found in *iText in Action*.

Comment: how to register fonts present inside a jar?